# Should "Home" be in navigation?

Tags: navigation

I always see home in the navigation and it seems redundant. Mainly because I would press the logo to go back home. The argument would go, not everyone knows the logo would take you home especially if we consider different levels of users. In that case, the home button should be in the navigation.

What if we have a big website that has 8 or more items in the navigation? Should we still keep "Home" or should we drop it?

At what point should we keep home? Or should home even be allowed on the navigation? Are there any studies or concepts that back it up?